# Coefficients of equations whose roots are primitive nth roots are -1, 0, 1 for n < 105.

Tags: number-theory

I came across an enigmatic comment without a specific reference in the book "Theory of Equations" by Joseph Thomas, p. 90 (see my paragraph following the quote for the context of the phrase 'resulting equation').

In addition, it is known that for $n < 105$ every coefficient in the resulting equation has one of the three values -1, 0, 1.

The context is the equation satisfied by all the primitive nth roots of unity. For example (x^6 -1) can be divided by (x^3 -1) and by x^2 - 1 to eliminate non-primitive cube and square roots. However this eliminates factor (x-1) twice because 1 is both a cube root and a square root. Thus a final (single) multiplication by (x - 1) to add it back in gives the equation x^2 - x + 1, satisfied by the sole primitive 6th root of unity. A similar procedure can be followed for other values of n.

I could not locate a reference showing this intriguing fact. Can anyone either explain it or provide a reference (or both)?

Comment: Note: My Latex escapes are showing up as blank (for me at least). I tried to edit it to use plain text such as x^6 -1 but the 'save edit' did not work either. Hope it shows up correctly, if not, apologies for the technical issue, the blanks above should be filled by x^6-1, x^3 -1, x^2 -1, x -1, x -1, and x^2 - x + 1. I have no idea what went wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of several simple facts. If we denote the $n-th$ cyclomatic polynomial by $F_n(X)$, then we have

$1) F_p(X) = X^{p-1} + X^{p-2} + \dots + X+1$ if $p$ is a prime number.

$2) F_{2m}(X) = F_m(-X) $ for every odd integer $m$.

$3) F_m(X^p) = F_m(X)F_{mp}(X)$ for all primes $p$ not dividing $m$.

$4) F_n(X) = F_m(X^{n/m})$ if $m$ is the product of all primes dividing $n$.

$5)$ for primes $p \ne q$, all coefficients of $F_{pq}(X)$ have absolute $1$.

from these facts, one can conclude that for $F_n$ to have coefficients with absolute greater than $1$, at least three distinct primes should divide $n$ (except for $2$). Then, the smallest candidate is $3\times 5 \times 7 = 105$. Some calculation shows that the coefficient of $X^{42}$ in $F_{105}(X)$ is actually $-2$.

**update:**

$F_n(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and is of order $\phi(n)$ (Euler totient function). Also, $$F_n(X) = \Pi_{(k, n) = 1, \space 1\le k\le n} (X-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}k}).$$

To prove the facts mentioned above, the main idea is to show that every root of LHS is a root of RHS (and vice versa). Then the result follows, since $F_n(X)$ is always monic and has $n$ distinct roots.

for $5)$, try using $3)$ with $m=q$, and look at it as an identity between power series.

Comment: I'm having difficulty locating references for these facts in any of my resources (and don't see easily how to prove them myself). Would you be able to supply any reference showing these properties? The paper by Emma Lehmer (given in the answer just below) proves a related result, but does not (as far as I can tell) go through the proof of this simpler fact. It references a paper from 1883 by Mignotti that I have been unable to locate!

Comment: Chapter 9 of this book: "Algebra, Volume I: Fields and Galois Theory, Authors: Lorenz, Falko" (some of these properties are left as exercises at the end of the book. See problems 9.8 and 9.9).

Answer (score 1):

This is well known, see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) on *Roots of unity*, with references. The first exception is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{105}$. Before all coefficients are $0,1,-1$, e.g.

\begin{align}
Φ_1(z) & = z − 1 \\ 
Φ_2(z) & = (z^2 − 1)⋅(z − 1)−1 = z + 1 \\
Φ_3(z) &= (z^3 − 1)⋅(z − 1)−1 = z^2 + z + 1\\
Φ_4(z) &= (z^4 − 1)⋅(z^2 − 1)−1 = z^2 + 1\\
Φ_5(z) &= (z^5 − 1)⋅(z − 1)−1 = z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1\\
Φ_6(z) &= (z^6 − 1)⋅(z^3 − 1)−1⋅(z^2 − 1)−1⋅(z − 1) = z^2 − z + 1\\
Φ_7(z) &= (z^7 − 1)⋅(z − 1)−1 = z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 +z + 1\\
Φ_8(z) &= (z^8 − 1)⋅(z^4 − 1)−1 = z^4 + 1\\
\end{align}

*Reference:* Emma Lehmer, On the magnitude of the coefficients of the cyclotomic polynomial, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society 42 (1936), no. 6, pp. 389–392.

Comment: The paper by Emma Lehmer proves a related result (that the coefficients can be made arbitrarily large), but does not (as far as I can tell) go through the proof of this simpler fact (I would like to understand the n<105 case first). It references a paper from 1883 by Mignotti for n<105 that I have been unable to locate!

Comment: The result for $n<105$ is easy to understand, but not so interesting. Even a computer program shows it directly. You could write such a program yourself. The first $8$ I have already computed in the list.